# Trying to build remove function, going wrong

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to build a remove function to my weather app, the function working only on the last place in the array I tried via MAP loop but I get too many renders errors.

This is the sandbox URL of my project -
https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-platform-cymzx?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

I don't get it if ts working on the last one why won't you on the first one?
(with for loop it's letting me edit only the last one, in map loop, it's saying too many renders)

Guys I stuck on this for 3 days now please help.

Comment: Routes in your sandbox are empty.

Comment: Sorry i dont think that i understood you, the routes on app ?

Comment: They not empty..

Comment: Probably you forgot to save your changes

Comment: @ezhikov can you try this link instead please ? https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-platform-cymzx?file=/App.js

Comment: This is what I see: https://imgur.com/a/z2rxNIb

Comment: Ok, I see your problem without routes

Comment: Glad to hear that, hope that you can help with this issue it's been teasing me for several days, everything that I tried not working properly I don't have a clue why it's happening.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your function:

```js
let deleteFunc = (name) => {
  allFavorite.map((item, index) => {
    console.log(item.name);
    let updatedFavorite = allFavorite.filter((item, i) => (item.name = name));
    setAllFavorite(updatedFavorite);
  });
};
```

First problem is that you mutate `item.name` in filter function.
Second problem is that you are seting state inside the map, so you call `setAllFavorite` for  each item in your `allFavorite`.

Your goal here is to construct new state first, and then apply it in one go, like this:

```js
let deleteFunc = (name) => {
  // this will return new array where item with name `name` removed, and will pass it into state setter
  setAllFavorite(allFavorite.filter((item) => item.name !== name));
};
```

Comment: I still get, too many renders didn't help with that error.

Comment: My guess would be that in your routes you call your function on render, probably inside your route, but without code I can't say